# How to compare data of two jsons and display icons according to result in vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vue-component

I have two arrays filled with JSON data: `generalQuestInfo` and `finishedQuestleafs`; object from `generalQuestInfo` looks like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Breaking News",
  alias: "BN",
  globalId: 1,
  platform: "Win64",
  pathway: {
    status: "Robot",
    name: "start case",
    leafs: ["start", "teleport", "take photo", "kill", "finish"]
  }
}
```

`finishedQuestleafs` looks like:

```
[
  {
    name: "start",
    questId: 1
  },
  {
    name: "teleport",
    questId: 1
  },
  {
    name: "take photo",
    questId: 1
  },
  {
    name: "kill",
    questId: 1
  },
  {
    name: "finish",
    questId: 1
  },
  {
    name: "start",
    questId: 2
  }
]
```

Where `id` from `generalQuestInfo` equals `questId` from `finishedQuestleafs`.
In Vue app I display table with data from `generalQuestInfo`.
But I need to compare values from `generalQuestInfo` `pathway.leafs` with `finishedQuestleafs` `name` according to ID. If `pahway.leafs` is in `finishedQuestleafs` with same ID, then I need to display `fas fa-check` icon, in other way - `fas fa-crash`.

How can I compare data in `generalQuestInfo` with `finishedQuestleafs` and display right icons? I tried to use two `v-for` directives, but it didn't work:(

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Path name</th>
      <th>Leafs Info</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-bind:key="data.id" v-for="data in generalQuestInfo" v-if="data.alias == 'BN' && isActive == 1">
      <td>{{ data.pathway.status }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.pathway.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.pathway.leafs }}</td> //instead of 5 data values here must be 5 icons according to finishedQuestleafs
    </tr>
    <tr v-bind:key="data.id" v-for="data in generalQuestInfo" v-if="data.alias == 'SAM' && isActive == 2">
      <td>{{ data.pathway.status }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.pathway.name }}</td>      
      <td>{{ data.pathway.leafs }}</td> //instead of 5 data values here must be 5 icons according to finishedQuestleafs  
    </tr>
    <tr v-else-if="isActive == 3">
      <td>NO INFO</td> 
    </tr> 
  </table>

data() {
  return {
    mainPageInfo: [],
    generalQuestInfo: [],
    finishedQuestleafs: [],
    isActive: 0             
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off create a method that will return appropriate icon. I believe the code of `getIconClass` method is self-explanatory. Then loop through `leafs` field in `template` and display name of the leaf and appropriate icon.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      generalQuestInfo: [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Breaking News",
        "alias": "BN",
        "globalId": 1,
        "platform": "Win64",
        "pathway": {
          "status": "Robot",
          "name": "start case",
          "leafs": ["start", "teleport", "take photo", "kill", "finish"]
        }
      }],
      finishedQuestleafs: [
        { name: "start", questId: 2 },
        { name: "teleport", questId: 1 },
        { name: "take photo", questId: 1 },
        { name: "kill", questId: 1 },
        { name: "finish", questId: 1 },
        { name: "start", questId: 2 }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getIconClass(id, leaf) {
      return this.finishedQuestleafs.find(item => item.questId === id && item.name === leaf) ? "fa fa-check" : "fa fa-bomb";
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Path name</th>
      <th>Leafs Info</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="data in generalQuestInfo" :key="data.id">
      <td>{{data.pathway.status}}</td>
      <td>{{data.pathway.name}}</td>
      <td>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(leaf, index) in data.pathway.leafs" :key="index">
          <i :class="getIconClass(data.id, leaf)"></i> {{ leaf }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: While this snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how this code answers the question improves it's long-term value.

Comment: @adiga, how do you prettify my code in browser? (default `tidier` gives me another result), but your result is much prettier :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a method to check while you're in the v-for loop.

```
<tr v-for="data in generalQuestInfo">
    <span v-if="hasQuestFinished(data.id, data.pathway.leafs)">
         <!-- display stuff if hasQuestFinished() returned true -->
    </span>
</tr>
```

And in your vue object (assuming you only want to check if its in the array:

```
methods:{
   hasQuestFinished(questID, givenQuests){
       finishedQuestleafs.forEach(function(leaf){
          if(leaf.questId == questID && givenQuests.indexOF(leaf.name) >= 0){
              return true;
          }
       });

       //finished the loop without returning means no match
       return false;
   }
}
```